# Make a nested loop for a JSON object in nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js

Hi I'm new to React and nodejs. I get from the user his preferences for certain categories in the json code for example:

```
{
    "sport" : {
        "tennis": "5",
        "running": "4",
        "swimming": "5"
    },
    "study" : {
        "history" : "0"
    } 
}
```

I want for each preference to create its own field in the "userPreferences" object.

This is the code I wrote down but I can not see what the error is here

```
exports.reduceUserPreferences = (data) => {
  let userPreferences = {};
  data.forEach(category => {
    category.forEach(preference => {
      category_preference_name = category.string + "_" + preference.string;
      if (!isEmpty(preference.trim())) userPreferences.category_preference_name = preference;
    });
  });
 
  //if (!isEmpty(data.tennis.trim())) userPreferences.sport_tennis = data.tennis;
  //if (!isEmpty(data.swimming.trim())) userPreferences.sport_swimming = data.swimming;
  //if (!isEmpty(data.running.trim())) userPreferences.sport_running = data.running;
  //if (!isEmpty(data.history.trim())) userPreferences.study_history = data.history;
 
  return userPreferences;
};
```

I want the "" object to have fields of all preferences along with the category to which they belong.

I can not understand what I am doing wrong, I linger on this code for several hours.

***add example***

I have another function similar to this function, the input is similar and the output is similar.
For example input:

```
{
    "bio": "hello there",
    "website": "",
    "location": "los angles"
}
```

Example function:

```
exports.reduceUserDetails = (data) => {
  let userDetails = {};
 
  if (!isEmpty(data.bio.trim())) userDetails.bio = data.bio;
  if (!isEmpty(data.website.trim())) {
    // https://website.com
    if (data.website.trim().substring(0, 4) !== 'http') {
      userDetails.website = `http://${data.website.trim()}`;
    } else userDetails.website = data.website;
  }
  if (!isEmpty(data.location.trim())) userDetails.location = data.location;
 
  return userDetails;
};
```

The output will be:
An object with the attribute of all preferences along with their value.

I was looking for examples with a nested loop, I could not find.

Comment: your error is here: `if (!isEmpty(preference.trim())) userPreferences.category_preference_name = preference;` should be using bracket notation like so: `if (!isEmpty(preference.trim())) userPreferences[category_preference_name] = preference;` you can't access a dynamic property using dot syntax, you have to use bracket syntax

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Dynamically access object property using variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4244896/dynamically-access-object-property-using-variable)

Comment: thank you for helping, i add an example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a couple of things you need to fix in your code.

First, when using a variable name as the key to extract from an object, user `obj[varName]`, not `obj.varName`.

(read more here: [Dynamically access object property using variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4244896/dynamically-access-object-property-using-variable))

Also, you're trying to loop an Object, not an array. To loop through the keys, use `Object.keys()`

Combining these two things you get the desired result, as you can see in this snippet. Also, for future questions, I highly recommend you make a snippet yourself.

```js
const jsonOriginal = {
    "sport" : {
        "tennis": "5",
        "running": "4",
        "swimming": "5"
    },
    "study" : {
        "history" : "0"
    } 
}

const reduceUserPreferences = (data) => {
  let userPreferences = {};
  Object.keys(data).forEach(category => {
    Object.keys(data[category]).forEach(preference => {
      category_preference_name = category + "_" + preference;
      const preferenceValue = data[category][preference].trim();
      if (preferenceValue !== '') userPreferences[category_preference_name] = preferenceValue;
    });
  });
 
  return userPreferences;
};

console.log(reduceUserPreferences(jsonOriginal))
```

Comment: thank you for help and for your advice, you right, in the nest time i'll use snippet